# Different single prefix in SIrange

Tags: siunitx, sirange

I'd like to write a SIrange `0.1Hz - 1kHz` but the only thing I found gives me `100mHz - 1kHz` like in the MWE. Is there a way of obtaining the first range without using two different SI commands?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\SIrange[range-phrase=--, exponent-to-prefix = true, zero-decimal-to-integer, scientific-notation = engineering]{0.1}{1000}{\hertz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: with simple `\SIrange{0.1}{1000}{\hertz}` you will obtain `0.1Hz to 1000Hz`, or with `\SIrange[range-phrase=--]{0.1}{1000}{\hertz}` you will obtain `0.1Hz–1000Hz`. is this what you looking for?

Comment: Nope, not exactly. I'm looking specifically for `0.1Hz - 1kHz` notation.

Comment: sorry, i misread the question, what you like to obtain is not possible with `SIrange` (as far as i know).

Comment: You'd like to `siunitx` realize that 1000 Hz are 1 kHz; however, what about 1000m²?