# Different prefix in SIrange (milli)

Tags: siunitx

I want to write 1 mHz to 1Hz using SIrange but I am unable to do so even after using the code given on the following link: [Different single prefix in SIrange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/423063/different-single-prefix-in-sirange)

Using that, if I write `\SIrange{0.001}{1}{\hertz}` in the text, I get result as 1mHz to 1mHz
if I try `\SIrange{1}{1000}{\milli\hertz}`; then it gives an error called 'Exponent 0 can not be converted'

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{%
    exponent-to-prefix = true,zero-decimal-to-integer,
    round-mode=figures, scientific-notation=engineering,
%   output-exponent-marker=\ensuremath{\,\mathrm{e}}
}
\begin{document}
            \SIrange{0.001}{1}{\hertz}\\
            \SIrange{1}{1000}{\milli\hertz}

Where I would like 1 \si{\milli\hertz} to 1\si{\hertz}
\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not just write it out, as in your MWE?

Comment: [Related bug report](https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/374)

Comment: Related: [siunitx miscalculating unit conversions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/521215/48973)